# issue using wavread in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have the this:

```
name = ['Anca', 'Bogdan', 'Francois', 'Jerome', 'Simina'];

for i=1:size(name,1)
temp = name(i,:);
tempwav = wavread(temp);
end
```

And I get this error:

```
Error in Load_data (line 7)
tempwav = wavread(temp);
```

meaning this line: `tempwav = wavread(temp);`

The .wav files are there I just don't know what is the problem. Pls help

Comment: `Ana` can be a name of a variable, but not a value. There is no strings in Matlab. Instead, use matrices of chars like `'Ana'`

Comment: I have edited my question, please look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of creating the variable `name` will result in the value `AncaBogdanFrancoisJeromeSimina`. Instead you should use a cell array (note the curly brackets)

```
name = {'Anca', 'Bogdan', 'Francois', 'Jerome', 'Simina'};

for i=1:length(name)
    temp = name{i};
    tempwav = wavread(temp);
end
```

Comment: now I get this Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in Load_data (line 6)
temp = name{i};

Comment: Note that I also added curly brackets to the first line `name = ...`.